Appropriate metrics for "Inter-Group Agreement"
I need to compare the results of a questionnaire that was given to two different groups of raters and somehow quantify how large the agreement between those groups is.
The questionnaire has 12 questions regarding the interpretation of certain requirement sentences and was answered by about 100 independent raters in the first group about 40 in the second group.
The results data that was collected is nominal data with no order or ranking.
Here is what an excerpt of the data looks like:
   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 2     2     3     2     1    
 2 2     2     3     2     1    
 3 1     4     4     4     1    
 4 2     3     3     3     2    
 5 1     1     4     2     4    
 6 2     2     3     2     2    
 7 1     1     3     1     1    
 8 2     3     3     2     2    
 9 2     2     3     3     3    
10 2     3     3     2     2  

The columns represent the different raters while each row represents a study object of the questionnaire, that can be rated either from 1-3 or 1-4 (again, nominal data).
Regarding a single group of raters, I could easily calculate the level of "intra-group" agreement using common Inter-Rater Reliability metrics like Lights' Kappa.
In fact, I already did this, and found a significant difference between the first group with a Kappa of 0.218 and the second group with a Kappa of 0.758 (calculated using kappam.light from the R package irr).
So it looks like the intra-group agreement has increased strongly in the second study.
But this doesn't help me if the ratings differ a lot from the most common ratings in the first group.
How would I calculate the level of "inter-group agreement" in this case.
What I could do, is just combine the results of the first group to the results of the seconds group (i.e. merge/ concatenate the tables) and calculate the joint IRR. This would show me the overall agreement while thinking of both groups as one large group.
But does this really say quantify how closely aligned the responses from the first group are to the second one?
If yes, do I need to have equal group sizes?
Or is there maybe a metric specifically designed to compare the level of agreement between two groups?
I found a similar question here, but in this case the author is handling with ordinal data.
Here it was suggested to calculate and compare the means of both groups and then perform a test about statistical significance, something that probably doesn't make much sense for nominal data.
